# Get iframe src param from inside the iframe itself

Tags: jquery, iframe

i have an iframe and need to capture the src attribute inside a javascript variable. This is how my iframe looks like

```
<iframe id="iframe_module_46081" name="iframe_module_46081" src="//myurl.com/tabs/495/campaigns/0ed3ffa8-5050-4a18-a5e3-f348d12a1304?signature=6aa3005368f163539976460246f2f0839c0fb3e3&amp;id=678326">
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
  var name = window.name;
  var src = ????;
})
</script>
</iframe>
```

I am able to get the name through window.name but not the src attribute. Any idea?

Comment: `top.document.getElementsByName(window.name)[0].src` should do it

Comment: @GGG: That won't work cross-domain.

Comment: @SLaks nothing will work cross domain =/ except `document.location`, obviously, but I assumed that wasn't working for him for some reason.

Comment: Is the script inside the document of the iframe or in the same document as the iframe?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If allowed by cross-domain checks, try `window.frameElement.src`. Otherwise, you are out of luck and left alone with `location.href`.

Comment: Why is the `location.href` choice unlucky?

Comment: Because the iframe could have navigated away from its original location

Comment: window.frameElement is null when cross-domain (I'm testing on Chrome)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `document.location`, just like any other document.
Each frame gets its own `document`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var src = top.document.getElementById("iframe_module_46081").src;
```

If you don't want to use jquery selector.

Comment: Thanks all but i just saw that the domain of the top iframe is different so i have crossdomain issues.

Answer (score 0):

As for me for now I ended up with saving initial iframe location.href to window object. (window.PROJECT_NAME_FIRST_URL_LOADED = window.location.href) Somewhere in application bootstrapping before application can change it's URL.

The other place where we could take it is history API, but it has no info about initial URL before you go back to initial state I believe.